# How to remotely execute Windows program in linux?

Tags: python, linux, windows, ssh, cygwin

I have tried accessing windows machine shell from linux using link http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/. It worked for me correctly. While using this i can able to ls or dir windows directory. But i can't execute python executable. It shows below error.

```
$ C:\\Python27\\python.exe
-bash: C:\Python27\python.exe: command not found
```

Now i am getting new error after some changes from the reply.I have mentioned whole scenario below.

```
Sanjayb@MA-SANJAYB-PC /cygdrive/d
$ /cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe ./scripts/Python_Scripts/avro_demo.py
 Usage : ./scripts/Python_Scripts/avro_demo.py <data_file>

Sanjayb@MA-SANJAYB-PC /cygdrive/d
$ cd ..

Sanjayb@MA-SANJAYB-PC /cygdrive
$ /cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe ./d/scripts/Python_Scripts/avro_demo.py
Error: Current working directory is a virtual Cygwin directory which does
not exist for a native Windows application.
Can't start native Windows application from here.

-bash: /cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe: Not a directory

Sanjayb@MA-SANJAYB-PC /cygdrive
$ cd ..

Sanjayb@MA-SANJAYB-PC /
$ /cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe ./cygdrive/d/scripts/Python_Scripts/avro_demo.py
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file './cygdrive/d/scripts/Python_Scripts/avro_demo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can i solve this problem. Should i skip this part and instead focus on client-server socket programming for this task. Please let me know at the earliest.

I have also tried freeSSHd setup, If i use password authentication it connects and gives me Windows shell. But i need password-less login. How can setup be done with this. When connecting from linux shell it says

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your Replies.
Finally got the answer.

First install cygwin under windows and follow the similar steps mentioned in [How to get ssh command-line access to windows 7 using cygwin](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/).
Then for executing windows program remotely follow below points.

1. First argument ( i.e. executable or script ) to be executed should be specified as cygwin paths

   **/cygdrive/c/python27/python.exe**
2. Further arguments to be specified as normal windows paths

   **D:\Scripts\Python_Scripts\list_directory.py 
   D:\Scripts\Python_Scripts**

Example

```
/cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe D:\\Scripts\\Python_Scripts\\list_directory.py D:\\Scripts\\Python_Scripts
```

Its working absolutely fine.